# Landsat 4-5 using SCP classification

Tags: landsat, scp

I am geodesy student from Slovenia. For my report I chose working with QGIS and I am having problems with SCP-classification.

So, I am working with Landsat 4-5 TM year 2006 and I would like to classify in 4 groups. I have done the cropping and preprocessing correcturres and have created raster od band set (stack bands) from bands 1,2,3,4,5 and 7.
When I start with SCP Dock and clicing ROI signature QGIS says:

> Warning [12] : The following signature will be excluded if using
>   Maximum Likelihood (singular covariance matrix). Macro: 1 ID: 8

I don't know how to fix the problem.